# FileNotFoundException with Leiningen and Ring

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I'm currently using Leiningen and Ring through the command line on a project I'm making called `reagent_test`, and I ran into a problem:

```
C:/...reagent_test>lein ring server
... huge chunk of errors
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate reagent_test/core__init.class or reagent_test/core.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
... more errors
```

*If anyone wants a gist for the issue, I'll make one if needed.*

The problem is, the files are all in the right place. Here's my `project.clj`:

```clojure
(defproject reagent-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5"]
            [lein-ring "0.10.0"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.456"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [leiningen "2.7.1"]
                 [reagent "0.6.0"]
                 [garden "1.3.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src/cljs"]}
                            :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/main.js"
                                        :pretty-print true}}}
  :ring {:handler reagent-test.core/-main})
```

And my project structure is like this (at least, for the relevant files):

```
src:
  clj:
    reagent_test:
      core.clj
  cljs:
    reagent_test:
      core.cljs
project.clj
```

In both `core.clj` and `core.cljs` I have this as my namespace:

```clojure
(ns reagent-test.core)
```

*NOTE: Folders have a colon and files don't.*

Answer (score 0):

In the namespace declaration at the top of the file you should use a dash:

```
(ns reagent-test.core)
```

Whereas the file (and all the directories above the file) should use underscores. So the filename should be `whatever/reagent_test/core.clj` or `whatever/reagent_test/core.cljs`.

Comment: That's what I did in both `core.clj` and `core.cljs` - sorry, I should have included that. Should I edit the post with the `namespace` snippet? Also, see the file structure thing - the `reagent_test` bit uses underscores instead of dashes.

Comment: Another thing your dependencies brackets don't line up: `[[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]` - seems like the final bracket is coming too early there.

Comment: Ah, nice catch! Thanks! That's a result of Visual Studio Code being terrible, will fix in the question.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `clj` source path, only a `cljs` one

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There is "src/cljs" for ClojureScript, but where is "src/clj" for something running on the server?

Comment: re "If anyone wants a gist for the issue, I'll make one if needed." yes you should include the full error message. Error messages are there to help diagnose problems. The lines you have trimmed contain the information about *why* your namespace couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Murphy has pointed out in the comments of his answer. Since you have changed your project directory structure a little, you will need to modify your `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject reagent-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5"]
            [lein-ring "0.10.0"]]
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.456"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [leiningen "2.7.1"]
                 [reagent "0.6.0"]
                 [garden "1.3.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src/cljs"]}
                            :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/main.js"
                                        :pretty-print true}}}
  :ring {:handler reagent-test.core/-main})
```

The addition is the `:source-paths` key which should specify the directory for the Clojure code. By default lein uses the `src` directory as the root for the Clojure source files.